# v-else-if not working in vuejs : Failed to resolve directive: else-if

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-directives

I am using "if" and "else-if" but is giving me compilation error.

> [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: else-if

this is my code

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
      lab_status : 2
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.28/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span v-if="lab_status==0">Inactive</span>
  <span v-else-if="lab_status==1">Active</span>
  <span v-else>Expired</span>
</div>
```

Please help me to resove this.

Answer (score 3):

`v-else-if` is added in vue 2.1.0 but you are using version `1.0.28`, that's why the error, update the vue version or use `v-if` only

```
<span v-if="lab_status==0">Inactive</span> 
<span v-if="lab_status==1">Active</span> 
<span v-if="lab_status!=1 && lab_status!=0">Expired</span>
```

See [`v-else-if`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-else-if)

Answer (score 3):

I think you have some wrong use of v-if and v-else.

Please check if you have a tag with v-if and v-else at the same time.

```
<span v-else v-if="lab_status==1">Inactive</span>
```

You can use v-else-if instead.

Answer (score 1):

From [this document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-else-if) `v-else-if` directive

> New in 2.1.0

So update your vuejs version

For now you can use only `v-if` and `v-else`

```
<span v-if="lab_status==0">Inactive</span>
<span v-if="lab_status==1">Active</span>
<span v-if="lab_status!=0&&lab_status!=1">Expired</span>
```

**Note:** In your case you have to use `v-if` only. If you use `v-else`, then for `lab_status=0` both `Inactive` and `Expired` will display.